# helm template - Helmfile, which way to go?

Tags: kubernetes-helm, argocd, helmfile

I am involved several projects CI/CD structures for deployment to Kubernetes with GitOps principles.

Some of the projects started before I joined them, I could not have to much influence on those and some others I was involved at the startup but I was not really happy with the end results so I was in a search of how would an ideal delivery pipeline for Kubernetes should look like.

After reading several peoples proposals and designs, I arrived a solution like the following.

[image: CI/CD Workflow]

I try to use Best Practices that there are consensus from several sources and the principles of [12 Factor App](https://12factor.net/).

It starts with a Git Repository per Service principle and having a Service Pipeline that is producing an Executable, a Docker Image and pushing to a Docker Registry and Helm Chart with Docker Image id and with the configuration that is valid for all environments and push it to a Helm Repository.

So with every commit to the Service Git Repositories, Service Pipelines will trigger to produces new Docker Images and Helm Charts (There is only one convention, Helm Chart Version will be only increased if there is an actual change to the structure of the Helm Templates, placing only the actual Docker Image Id into the Helm Chart will not bump the Version of the Helm Charts).

A commit to the Service Git Repository would also trigger the Environment Pipeline for the Dev Environment (this is oversimplified to be able to keep the size of the diagram in check, for Feature and Bugfix branches Environment Pipeline can also create additional Namespaces under Dev k8s cluster).

At this point, is one big change from my previous production implementation of similar pipelines and the reason of this question. In those implementations, at this point Environment Pipeline would get all Service Helm Charts from Helm Repository with the help of the Helm Umbrella Chart (unlike the diagram below) and execute 'helm upgrade --install appXXX -n dev -f values-s1.yaml -f values-s2.yaml -f values-s3.yaml -f values-s4.yaml -f values-s5.yaml' which works but the disadvantage being the auditing.

We can identify by inspecting K8s Cluster what we deployed a later point in the time but it would be painful, so my idea is to follow GitOps principles (and many sources agrees with me) and render the manifests from Helm Umbrella Chart with 'helm template' during the 'Environment Pipeline' and commit those to Environment Repository, so that way, first those can be much more easily audited and secondly I can deploy those with the help of the Continuous Deployment tool like ArgoCD.

Now that I explained the precondition, we are arrived to my actual question, I also read from the same sources I mentioned, 'helmfile' is also an awesome tool when I read the documentation, it has really nice tool to prevent boilerplate code but considering, I am planning to synchronise the the state in the Environment Git Repository with ArgoCD, I will not use 'helmfile sync' and 'helm template' does basically what 'helmfile template' does, is using 'helmfile' also in this workflow is an overkill? Additionally I think the concept of Helmfile's 'environment.yaml' collides what I try to achieve with Environment Git Repository.

And secondly, if I decide also to use 'helmfile', mainly because of the awesome extra templating functions preventing the boilerplate, how should I integrate it with ArgoCD, it seems previously it could be integrated over...

```
data:
  configManagementPlugins: |
  - name: helmfile
    generate:
      command: ["/bin/sh", "-c"]
      args: ["helmfile -q template --include-crds --skip-tests"]
```

but it seems now 'configManagementPlugins' is deprecated, how should I integrate it with ArgoCD?

Thx for answers.

Comment: any updates for your own question now?

Comment: Well as you can see there wasn't a concrete answer to the question, by the time I decided to render my Helm Umbrella Charts with 'helmfile template' function from GitHib / GitLab / Azure / etc Pipeline and place it to a Git Repository so ArgoCD can deploy those. I wrote a blog about it, you can read the whole story here https://mehmetsalgar.wordpress.com/2023/02/05/ideal-ci-cd-pipeline-for-your-kubernetes-deployments/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer from @Vanderworld is really useful but I followed another pattern, which you can read the concept on this [blog](https://mehmetsalgar.wordpress.com/2023/02/05/ideal-ci-cd-pipeline-for-your-kubernetes-deployments/) and a complete implementation with Azure DevOps Pipelines in this [blog](https://mehmetsalgar.wordpress.com/2023/02/26/azure-devops-pipelines-for-an-ideal-ci-cd-for-your-kubertnetes-deployments/).

Basically I decided to render k8s manifest with helmfile template and commit the manifests to GiT and let ArgoCD read from there.

Answer (score 1):

> but it seems now 'configManagementPlugins' is deprecated, how should I integrate it with ArgoCD?

You need to use configManagementPlugins through sidecars and not the usual ConfigMap, see [here](https://argo-cd.readthedocs.io/en/stable/operator-manual/config-management-plugins/#sidecar-plugin).

The ConfigMap would roughly look like the following, and you then mount the ConfigMap into the sidecar like [here](https://argo-cd.readthedocs.io/en/stable/operator-manual/config-management-plugins/#register-the-plugin-sidecar).

The rough ConfigMap:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata: 
  name: helmfile-plugin
  namespace: argocd
data:
  plugin.yaml: |
    apiVersion: argoproj.io/v1alpha1
    kind: ConfigManagementPlugin
    metadata:
      name: helmfile
    spec:
      discover:
        find:
          command:
            - sh
            - -c
            - |
              find . -type f -name helmfile.yaml && find . -type d -name helmfile.d
      generate:
        command:
          - sh
          - -c
          - |
            helmfile template --skip-deps --include-crds "${ARGOCD_ENV_CLUSTER_ENV:+--environment="${ARGOCD_ENV_CLUSTER_ENV}"}";
      init:
        command:
          - sh
          - -c
          - |
            helmfile repos "${ARGOCD_ENV_CLUSTER_ENV:+--environment="${ARGOCD_ENV_CLUSTER_ENV}"}";
      version: v1.0
```

Comment: Thx for the input, really nice to know, the Helm Umbrella Chart concept that I discussed in the blog, I rather realise the Helm Template from pipeline and commit the manifests that are generated to GiT and let the ArgoCD read those from GiT but again thx a lot for the information about how to configure  ConfigManagementPlugin, I am sure it would be handy at some point...